# Reset INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I created a table called DRINK. I inserted two rows in to it initially. When upgraded, I would like to delete both rows and reset my Primary Key to 1. I am getting the rows to delete but am not having any luck resetting the primary key. Does anybody know the syntax on how to do that or if it's even possible? Here's the function which is called from my onUpdate function:

```
    private void updateMyDatabase(SQLiteDatabase db, int olderVersion, int newVersion){
    Log.v("DatabaseHelper","UPDATE MY DATABASE");
    if (olderVersion<1){
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE DRINK (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + "NAME TEXT, "
                + "DESCRIPTION TEXT, "
                + "IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID INTEGER);");
        insertDrink(db,"latte","Espresso and Steamed Milk",R.drawable.latte);
        insertDrink(db, "cappuccino", "This a Cappuccino", R.drawable.cap);
    }
    if (olderVersion < 2){
        db.execSQL("delete from DRINK");
        db.execSQL("alter table AUTO_INCREMENT =1"); //*** NEED HELP HERE***
        insertDrink(db, "coff", "Espresso and Steamed Milk", R.drawable.latte);
    }
}
```

I found this piece of code online but it's not working. Thank you.

```
db.execSQL("alter table AUTO_INCREMENT =1");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleteing the rows won't reset ROWID.

SQLite documentation states:

> SQLite keeps track of the largest ROWID that a table has ever held
>   using the special SQLITE_SEQUENCE table. The SQLITE_SEQUENCE table is
>   created and initialized automatically whenever a normal table that
>   contains an AUTOINCREMENT column is created. The content of the
>   SQLITE_SEQUENCE table can be modified using ordinary UPDATE, INSERT,
>   and DELETE statements. But making modifications to this table will
>   likely perturb the AUTOINCREMENT key generation algorithm.

This sql should do what you need:

```
UPDATE SQLITE_SEQUENCE SET seq = <n> WHERE name = <table>
```

Where n is the sequence you wish to set and table is your table name

Comment: I got this log error:    E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) near "<": syntax error

Comment: Did you change <n> to the value you want?

Comment: Yeah I did. Here's the exact line of code:      db.execSQL("UPDATE SQLITE_SEQUENCE SET seq = <1> WHERE name = 'DRINK'");

Comment: db.execSQL("UPDATE SQLITE_SEQUENCE SET seq = 1 WHERE name = 'DRINK'");

Comment: If you want to start from 1 (one), dont forget to set to 0:
db.execSQL("UPDATE SQLIT_SEQUENCE SET seq=0 WHERE name="table_name"

Comment: can anyone tell me the way to do this for room ? tried almost everything